# How to set PATH for Cygwin bash

Tags: bash, cygwin, system-paths

I have script `foo.sh` in my Cygwin directory `/usr/local/bin`. I can run it using `mintty`, but not using bash.

When I started, the situation was as follows:

```
foo.sh in mintty   -   WORKING
foo.sh in bash     -   NOT WORKING
```

Then I added line `export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"` to my `.bashrc` file. Now situation is as below:

```
foo.sh in mintty   -   WORKING
foo.sh in bash     -   WORKING
however
bash -c foo.sh     -   NOT WORKING
```

I need the last method of running the script to work. I will use it in my executable, which is compiled for Windows, so the command musts work in `cmd`.

My questions are:

1. How to set variable `PATH`, to work with `bash -c`.
2. Why `/usr/local/bin` is not in `PATH` by default? Is it any reason to don't do that I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? If so, how?

Comment: @Will Nope. I used some workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

The `.bashrc` file is only executed for non-login shells. For environments like this, I recommend including `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`:

```
echo '. "${HOME}/.bashrc"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

This way, your `.bashrc` will be included for both login and non-login shells.